# Facebook iOS SDK - Why are graph requests still completed after connection is canceled?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to let the user cancel an image post request, as how the Facebook iOS app works.

I called 'cancel' on request.connection as described in this [previous discussion](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4958912/facebook-api-how-to-cancel-graph-request). However, the images are still posted. SDK documentation suggests that this is the correct way to cancel requests. What am I missing here? Is there no way to effectively cancel graph requests?

Appreciate the help!